# JSON PHP Querying

Tags: php, json

I have a question about querying JSON structures that make use of nested objects. In order to explain, I will use some examples.

For Examples Sake, the variable **$json** is a JSON file:

```
movies [{"name":"good movie", "poster":"link"}]
```

Normally after I've used the **json_decode()** function on a JSON file I can do something like

```
$newFiles = $json["movies"];

foreach ($newFiles as $file) {
$name = $file["name"]; }
```

But, lets say I have this JSON File:

```
movies[{"name":"good movie", "poster": {"original":"link", "smaller":"link"}}]
```

How would I get the value of **"original"**, I've tried doing something like:

```
$newFiles = $json["movies"];

foreach ($newFiles as $file) {
$poster = $file["poster" -> "original"]; }
```

That, however, doesn't work. I can't find the appropriate syntax to query this. Any help appreciated, thanks in advance!

Comment: Is the answer provided is answering the question?

Answer (score 1):

When you decode your json with [json_decode()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php), set the second parameter to true, as so:

```
<?php
$movies = '[{"name":"good movie", "poster": {"original":"link", "smaller":"link"}}]';
$movieArray = json_decode($movies,true);

foreach($movieArray as $movie){
    print_r($movie['poster']['original']);
}
?>
```

This will allow you to convert returned objects into associative arrays. Therefore it is possible to do something like `$movie['poster']['original']`.